# How to enable jQuery UI slider clicking on the track?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, seekbar, audio-player

I'm trying to create a slider whose handle jumps to where one clicks on the track, in addition to being able to be dragged.

Right now, I can drag it; but it doesn't respond when I click somewhere on the track.

PS:  Just found the reason. I have another div placed on top of the slider track acting as a progress bar, so that when I click on the slider track, I'm actually clicking the progress bar div. My solution was to set the slider div's background to "transparent" and "z-index: 2" in the css file. Apparently this allows the display of the progressbar div underneath it while preserving the function of clicking on the track.

```
#audio_slider{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 12px;
    width: 95%;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid white;


    z-index: 2;
    background: transparent;
}

#audio_progress {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 6px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    width: 95%;
    height: 11px;
    display:inline-block;

}
```

Comment: Your example works https://jsfiddle.net/wbheaeen/

Comment: @H77 I found the reason. I have another div placed on top of the slider track acting as a progress bar, so that when I click on the slider track, I'm actually clicking the progress bar div. Do you know a good solution to this? Can I make the slider track transparent?

Comment: Could you post an example here where the problem can be reproduced? And if you make the slider track transparent how will you see it/click it?

Comment: @H77 Just solved. Thank you. I set the slider div's background to "transparent" in the css file. Sure!